# Strange behaviour of slugify function

Tags: django, slug

It works perfectly from the admin site. But the code below doesn't work properly(some characters are missing, like Turkish "ı") in some languages.

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True, db_index=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Foo, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

For example, let's assume that the name is "ışçğö" and then slug becomes "scgo" when it should be "iscgo" instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [`SlugField`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#slugfield) behavior by definition. A slug is supposed to be part of a URL. Even though URLs might support non-latin characters, these are not supported inside slugs.

> Slug is a newspaper term. A slug is a
>   short label for something, containing
>   only letters, numbers, underscores or
>   hyphens. *They're generally used in URLs.*

---

The results you are getting aren't consistent with Django behavior:

```
>>> from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
>>> v = u"ışçğö"
>>> slugify(v)
u'isg'
```

Where exactly are you getting these results?

Comment: Thanks. I know, but the admin site turns it into "iscgo" which is right. I just want to make it work the same way.

Comment: Very strange, I got "iscgo" when I run the code above in console.

Comment: Hmm, the results might be dependent on display encoding.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [slughifi](http://trac.django-fr.org/browser/site/trunk/project/links/slughifi.py?rev=47) function for better slug functionality (thanks to [Markus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/389143/markus-glock) for showing me this).